# wifi connections not showing up

Tags: wireless

wifi connections not showing up:
my laptop was working fine (wifi) till last night!
but for some reasons it stopped working,
it is not showing up any previous wifi connections!
actually there is no wifi option in the network manager
pls help!

Comment: Try this: `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: still its not changing,after restarting only ethernet option is there,wireless option is still not coming.@Jos

Comment: here this is the output:               08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
 DeviceName: Mediatek WLAN Mediatek Civic MT7630E bgn 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB HMCWW
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [103c:197c]
 Kernel modules: wl
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)..............@pilot6